# Angular Unit Tests: testing a simple promise-based function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a very simple mock service that I have created in my unit test for injecting into another object that I am testing.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($q, $timeout) {
  ItemService = {
    one: function(id) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve({
          id: id
        });
      }, 0);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}));
```

Now I'd like to write a simple unit test that makes sure that this service returns the correct promise.

```
describe('mock service', function() {
  it('should return a promise', function() {
    // test comes here
    ItemService.one('123').then(function(item) {
      // ... but doesn't make it here
      expect(item.id).toEqual('123');
    });
  });  
});
```

However, the code inside `then()` never gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $timeout service used in unit tests is a [mocked $timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout), that needs to be flushed (just like $httpBackend). This allows testing code that waits for 10 minutes without actually waiting for 10 minutes in the test:

```
ItemService.one('123').then(function(item) {
  // ... but doesn't make it here
  expect(item.id).toEqual('123');
});
$timeout.flush(1);
```

I'm not sure that this automatically resolves the promise though, because promises are resolved the the scope is $applied. So you might additionally need

```
$rootScope.$apply();
```

Of course, $timeout and $rootScope need to be injected in the test.

Comment: Thank you, apply()ing worked. $timeout above turned out to be unnecessary, as the promise is trivial.